# getting functions from a character string

Tags: r

In [Burn's R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), p. 65, the following code can be found:

```
funs <- c(’mean’, ’median’)
eval(as.name(funs[2]))(data)
```

However, for me this generates:

```
Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
  'x' must be atomic
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'closure'
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this a bug/typo in the book?

Comment: These are LaTeX quotes, you need to change them to standard R quotes such as `'` or `"` and replace `data` with some *real* data (`data` is a function in R, see `?data`). Try for example `funs <- c('mean', 'median') ; get(funs[2])(1:5)`. Or `eval(as.name(funs[2]))(1:5)`.